# Are integrals continuous with respect to measure

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Consider the integral as a function of the measure:

$$F(\mu) = \int_\Omega f(x) d\mu(x)$$

where $f$ is some function with conditions to be determined.

I think can answer the question for the following case. Suppose $\mu^n \rightharpoonup \mu$ in the sense of weak convergence of measures. Then, if $f$ is any continuous and bounded function on $\Omega$, then $F(\mu^n) \rightarrow F(\mu)$.

What is a more general criterion? And when is $F$ lipschitz continuous?

Comment: I'm unsure about whether this can be made significantly more general. Surely, if $F$ is Lipschitz continuous this does not need to hold: Simply consider $F(x)=x$, then such continuity would imply convergence of means, which is not true in general. Also worth noting, if $F$ is positive and continuous, Fatou's Lemma gives lower semi-continuity.

Comment: @SmallDeviation can you explain your statement "if 
 is Lipschitz continuous this does not need to hold" and the example $F(x)=x$?